# Div within an anchor tag not taking up entire width? HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I've got a `div` tag inside an `a` tag. The `a` tag, which has class "project" has a background image. I'm trying to make several little `300px by 300px`  boxes, in which there is an image, with text centered (vert and hor), so that you'd click the image and it'll take you to a link.

I want to get a hover effect (on desktops) so that when you go over this `a` tag, which has the image as a `background image`, the image darkens, making the white text more visible. On mobile, this image is always darkened so the text is clearly visible.

**Here's the problem:** I have everything working fine, but the "overlay" `div` within the `a` tag is not taking up the entire width of the a tag (300px by 300px box). *Therefore,* when I hover over the `a` tag, and the "overlay" `div` turns dark, there's a little space on both sides that is not dark.

**Here is some of the code:**

**HTML for the projects section:**

```
<!-- Projects Showcase Section -->
<div class="projects-section">

    <div class="wrapper">

        <a href="link-to-project" class="project">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h1>Project Name</h1>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="link-to-project" class="project">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h1>Project Name</h1>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="link-to-project" class="project">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h1>Project Name</h1>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.projects-section {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.project {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('../assets/img/p1-min.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}

.project:nth-child(2) {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('../assets/img/p2-min.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.project:nth-child(3) {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('../assets/img/p3-min.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.project .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transition: 0.4s all ease;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.overlay:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

**Here's an image of what the problem looks like:**
[image: The Problem]

As you can see, the left and right side of the "overlay" `div` are not fully expanded to fit inside the `a` tag, making it obvious there's a div there.

Please help me fix it, thank you.

Comment: Looks like you have left/right padding on the anchor.

Comment: @KoshVery I was aware of that rule too, but I don't use flexbox much; when I inspect the `a` tags, in Chrome at least, they are receiving `display:block` because of the parent flexbox display property (Note: I had to use the computed styles in dev tools, as the normal list of styles showed flexbox as being inherited but grayed out - but computed shows block).

Comment: @Kosh: an [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) is ‘transparent,’ and can contain any element types (so long as the content html is itself valid) with the exception of interactive content.

Comment: @KoshVery supporting David's comment : http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: Yes guys, you are right. It is HTML5 valid though HTML5 is still a recommendation not a living standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the left/right padding on the anchors, and extend the width of your `.project` elements to 320px, it should look how you want it - though I'm not sure if you have the padding there for some other purpose.

```
.project {
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/300x300');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dtwLjqx4/

Comment: Yeah, this worked, though i didnt need to change it to 320px. Thank you